# Is AWS Lambda "duration" measured in real time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

With AWS Lambda, I am charged for the "duration" of a function execution. Is duration measured in CPU time or real time? In other words, am I being charged while blocked on IO operations such as querying a SQL database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From their pricing details page(https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/): "Duration is calculated from the time your code begins executing until it returns or otherwise terminates, rounded up to the nearest 100ms." So I would say that means you get charged while you are waiting for a response from an external resource.

That also means your timeout duration needs to be long enough to account for slow responses from the external resource or Lambda will timeout.

Answer (score 1):

It is all the realtime that your function uses the lambda serverless computing power